# NameError en un bot de Discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, nodejs

he intentado recrear un bot que se ha cerrado pero tengo un error cuando intento iniciar el bot (Pokecord). Cuando lo intento iniciar aparece este error:

```
File "C:\Users\meganano202\Desktop\PokeCord-master\var_secrets.py", line 4, in <module>
CLIENT_SECRET = yWW55ovf6-KxETrB1v18x_-QLUJaoaam #Discord given
NameError: name 'yWW55ovf6' is not defined
```

he probado cambiando de clave pero siempre dice lo mismo, os dejo el código para que le echéis un vistazo

```
from var_secrets import *

import os
import json
import pickle
import random
import asyncio

# api #
import discord
from imgurpython import ImgurClient

# DISCORD  VARS #
#client = discord.Client()

BOT_PREFIX = ";"
CHANNEL_IDs  = ("449281327988998156")

# PYTHON VALS #
class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

# Globals #

imgr_client = ImgurClient(imgr_client_id, imgr_client_secret)

# Image Vars #
white = (255,255,255,255)
black = (0, 0, 0, 255)
```

y ese código abre este para obtener la información:

```
MASTER_ID = None #Discord ID

CLIENT_ID = None #Discord given
CLIENT_SECRET = None #Discord given
TOKEN = None #Discord given

imgr_client_id = None #IMGR Given
imgr_client_secret = None #IMGR Given
```

muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

El problema se resolvía tan fácil como añadir " en la parte que fallaba. Seria tal que:

```
MASTER_ID = None #Discord ID

CLIENT_ID = None #Discord given
CLIENT_SECRET = "None" #Discord given
TOKEN = "None" #Discord given

imgr_client_id = "None" #IMGR Given
imgr_client_secret = "None" #IMGR Given
```

En **Master_id** y **Client_id** no hace falta añadirlo